# ocaml polymorphism - coercing a type to be complient with a polymorphic type

Tags: polymorphism, ocaml

I'm trying to do a simple, hierarchical parametric polymorphic type which, when I try and apply it, throws up a wrong type error.

```
module H : sig

  type 'a value
  type 'a to_value_children = ('a value -> 'a value list option)
  type 'a node

  val hierarchy: 'a value -> 'a to_value_children -> 'a node

end = struct

  type 'a value
  type 'a to_value_children = ('a value -> 'a value list option)
  type 'a node = {
    data: 'a value;
    children: 'a node list option;
  }

  let hierarchy value to_value_children =
    let rec build v =
      match to_value_children v with
      | None -> {data=v; children = None}
      | Some c -> (
        let node_children =
          List.fold_left (fun a c' ->
            (build c')::a
          ) [] c
        in
        {data=v; children = Some node_children}
      )
    in
    build value

end


type data =
  {
    name: string;
    children: data list option;
  }

let data =
  {
    name = "root";
    children = None
  }

let to_value_children = fun value -> value.children

let () =
  H.hierarchy data to_value_children |> ignore
```

Compiling `H.hierarchy data to_value_children` gives the following error: `data: This expression has type data but an expression was expected of type 'a H.value`

Can anyone suggest how I can tie the two types together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really not clear what the type `'a value` is supposed to be. Currently, it only visible effect is to ensure that the module `H` is unusable. With the current signature of `H` there is simply no way to build any value of type `'a value`. Furthermore, since `'a value` is an abstract type in the module implementation, this is true even inside the module implementation.
If I am to hazard a guess, you were either trying to write:

```ml
module H = struct
  type 'a to_value_children = 'a -> 'a list option
  type 'a node = {
    data: 'a;
    children: 'a node list option;
  }

  let hierarchy value to_value_children =
    let rec build data =
      let children =
          match to_value_children data with
          | None -> None
          | Some c -> Some (List.map build c) in
      { data; children }
    in
    build value

end

type data =
  {
    name: string;
    children: data list option;
  }

let data =
  {
    name = "root";
    children = None
  }

let to_value_children value =  value.children

let h =
  H.hierarchy data
```

where there is simply no `'a value` at all, and `hierarchy` works with any type with a possible `to_value_children` function.

Or the functor version

```ml
type 'a to_children = 'a -> 'a list option
module H(Lower: sig type value val to_children: value to_children end) = struct
  type 'a node = {
    data: 'a;
    children: 'a node list option;
  }
  type value = Lower.value node
  let rec hierarchy data  =
      let children =
          match Lower.to_children data with
          | None -> None
          | Some c -> Some (List.map hierarchy c) in
      { data; children }

   let to_children x = x.children

end
...
module Hdata = H(struct
    type value = data
    let to_children v = v.children
end)
let h1 =
  Hdata.hierarchy data
module H2data = H(Hdata)
let h2 = H2data.hierarchy h1
```

This version creates a functor that creates isomorphic but incompatible node-like type from a node-like type.

Comment: Thanks - I was trying to avoid using a functor and was blind to my ```'a value``` mistake

Answer (score 1):

Your signature for `H` defines `H.value` as an abstract type. So the only OCaml values that can be of this type are values returned by functions in `H`. However, there are no functions in `H` that return something of type `H.value`.

For this reason, it's not possible to call `H.hierarchy`. In essence you have defined a module that has no usable interface.

Comment: Another elementary mistake on my part - I didn't realise the implication of ```'a value``` - thanks for the answer